# NSRangeException at particular Segue

Tags: ios, swift, nsrangeexception

I have this particular segue that keeps giving me NSRangeException. I have no code at all in prepareForSegue. I put a break point in viewdidload of that view controller and it is executed with no problem. Seems that the exception occurs in IOS system code.

This is detail of exception

> 2015-09-16 07:21:24.939 Vote Strategic[7523:1117149] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[**NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array'
>   *** First throw call stack:
>   (
>       0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010a699c65 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
>       1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010c204bb7 objc_exception_throw + 45
>       2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010a583093 -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:] + 227
>       3   My Strategic                      0x000000010a008cfa _TPAo13 + 42
>       4   My Strategic                      0x000000010a009c35 _TTRXFo_dSi_aPSs9AnyObject__XFo_dSi_oPS_** + 21
>       5   My Strategic                      0x000000010a0094ec _TFFC14My_Strategic4Rest9getRidingFS0_FSST_U_FTGSQCSo13NSURLResponse_GSQCSo6NSData_GSQCSo7NSError__T_ + 1260
>       6   My Strategic                      0x000000010a009cea _TTRXFo_oGSQCSo13NSURLResponse_oGSQCSo6NSData_oGSQCSo7NSError__dT__XFdCb_dGSQS__dGSQS0__dGSQS1___dT__ + 90
>       7   CFNetwork                           0x000000010c8a98c5 **67+[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:queue:completionHandler:]_block_invoke_2 + 155
>       8   Foundation                          0x000000010ab5a57f __NSBLOCKOPERATION_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK** + 7
>       9   Foundation                          0x000000010aa9b0b2 -[NSBlockOperation main] + 98
>       10  Foundation                          0x000000010aa7d774 -[__NSOperationInternal _start:] + 645
>       11  Foundation                          0x000000010aa7d383 __NSOQSchedule_f + 184
>       12  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010dcfe614 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
>       13  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010dce56a7 _dispatch_queue_drain + 2176
>       14  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010dce4cc0 _dispatch_queue_invoke + 235
>       15  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010dce83b9 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 1359
>       16  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010dce9b17 _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 111
>       17  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x000000010e06b637 _pthread_wqthread + 729
>       18  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x000000010e06940d start_wqthread + 13
>   )
>   libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please put exception breakpoint and run in debug mode to stop at the exact line of crash.

Clearly you are trying to access objects from an empty array which is bound to crash. It is always advisable to put a check on array size before accessing its elements.

[image]

Comment: After adding exception breakpoint, I found where exception occurs. It's from my asynchronous call to REST api. Thank!